# How do I install softwares in openbsd?

Tags: openbsd

I want to install Firefox but been having issues. So how do I install softwares and games in OpenBsd?

I was following this guide: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/openbsd-install-firefox-web-browser/

Comment: `pkg_add -i firefox` in a terminal as the `root` user should install firefox...

Comment: Just a quick note on content, Jon. Your posts are already & always signed, so there's no need to include a signature in your posts. Thanks!

Comment: You should describe the problems you were having in your post description in higher detail

Comment: @sezanzeb I was following this guide. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/openbsd-install-firefox-web-browser/

Comment: @David Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you link to is over 10 years old, although things haven't changed that much since then, as far as installing packages go: you still install packages with `pkg_add` (which has to be ran by `root` or through tools like `doas`).

OpenBSD's documentation is renowned for its thoroughness.  Reading the project's [FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq) is very much recommended for new users, and has [a specific section concerning its package system](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html).  The quality of its `man` pages is also quite high.  Make sure you check the one for `pkg_add` (either by issuing `man pkg_add` on a terminal or by checking [man.openbsd.org](http://man.openbsd.org/pkg_add)).

Unrelatedly to OpenBSD, and as has been commented by @sezanzeb, you should be more specific as to what isn't going on as planned or expected. "having issues" is way to vague for anyone to be able to efficiently help you.